Django View Causing ConnectionError in Production When Fetching TMDB API Data
Problem
I am encountering a ConnectionError when trying to fetch data from the TMDB API and add it to my database in a production environment. The error message indicates that the connection was reset by the peer:
This issue does not occur in the local development environment. Below are the relevant parts of my views.py and nginx settings.
Code Snippets
views.py:
def SeriesAddView(request):
    org = Org.objects.first()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        tmdb_id = request.POST.get('tmdb_id')

        reqUrl = f"https://api.themoviedb.org/3/tv/{tmdb_id}?language=en-US"

        headersList = {
        "accept": "application/json",
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {org.tmdb_token}"
        }

        payload = ""

        series_details = requests.request("GET", reqUrl, data=payload,  headers=headersList)
        update_series = Series.objects.filter(tmdb_id=tmdb_id).first()

        if series_details.status_code == 200:
            data = series_details.json()
            genre_data = data["genres"]

            genre_list = []
            for genre_data in genre_data:
                genre_id = genre_data.get("id")
                genre_name = genre_data.get("name")
                if genre_id and genre_name:
                    genre = Genre.objects.filter(genre_id=genre_id).exists()
                    try:
                        genre = Genre.objects.get(genre_id=genre_id)
                    except Genre.DoesNotExist:
                        genre = Genre.objects.create(genre_id=genre_id, name=genre_name)
                    genre_list.append(genre)

            # Check if the poster image already exists
            img_path = data["poster_path"]
            poster_path = f"media/posters/tv{img_path}"
            if not os.path.exists(poster_path):
                # Save the poster image locally
                poster_url = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original" + img_path
                poster_response = requests.get(poster_url)
                if poster_response.status_code == 200:
                    with open(f"media/posters/tv/series{img_path}", 'wb') as f:
                        f.write(poster_response.content)

            if update_series:
                # Update the existing movie
                update_series.adult = data["adult"]
                update_series.title = data["name"]
                update_series.original_title = data["original_name"]
                update_series.overview = data["overview"]
                update_series.release_date = data["first_air_date"]
                update_series.status = data["status"]
                update_series.tagline = data["tagline"]
                update_series.type = data["type"]
                update_series.poster_path = f"posters/tv/series{img_path}"
                update_series.genre.clear()
                update_series.genre.add(*genre_list)
                update_series.save()
            else:
                # Create a new movie
                create_series = Series.objects.create(
                tmdb_id = data["id"],
                adult = data["adult"],
                title = data["name"],
                original_title = data["original_name"],
                overview = data["overview"],
                release_date = data["first_air_date"],
                status = data["status"],
                tagline = data["tagline"],
                type = data["type"],
                poster_path = f"posters/tv/series{img_path}"
                )
                create_series.genre.add(*genre_list)
                create_series.save()

            # Add seasons for the series
            seasons = data.get("seasons", [])
            for season_data in seasons:
                season_number = season_data.get("season_number")
                if season_number:
                    add_season(tmdb_id, season_number, org.tmdb_token)
        else:
            messages.success(request, 'Request was not successful. Status code:', series_details.status_code)

        messages.success(request, 'Series Created Successfully')
        return render(request, 'Tv/SeriesAddView.html')
    return render(request, 'Tv/SeriesAddView.html')

def add_season(tmdb_id, season_number, tmdb_token):
    reqUrl = f"https://api.themoviedb.org/3/tv/{tmdb_id}/season/{season_number}?language=en-US"
    
    headersList = {
        "accept": "application/json",
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {tmdb_token}"
    }

    response = requests.get(reqUrl, headers=headersList)
    
    if response.status_code == 200:
        data = response.json()
        series = get_object_or_404(Series, tmdb_id=tmdb_id)

        img_path = data.get("poster_path")
        if img_path:
            poster_path = f"media/posters/tv/season/{tmdb_id}{img_path}"
            if not os.path.exists(poster_path):
                poster_url = f"https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original{img_path}"
                poster_response = requests.get(poster_url)
                if poster_response.status_code == 200:
                    os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(poster_path), exist_ok=True)
                    with open(poster_path, 'wb') as f:
                        f.write(poster_response.content)

        update_season = Season.objects.filter(series=series, season_number=season_number).first()
        
        if update_season:
            update_season.title = data.get("name", "")
            update_season.overview = data.get("overview", "")
            update_season.release_date = data.get("air_date", "")
            update_season.poster_path = f"posters/tv/season/{tmdb_id}{img_path}"
            update_season.save()
        else:
            Season.objects.create(
                series=series,
                title=data.get("name", ""),
                overview=data.get("overview", ""),
                season_number=season_number,
                release_date=data.get("air_date", ""),
                poster_path=f"posters/tv/season/{tmdb_id}{img_path}"
            )
        # Add seasons for the series
        episodes = data.get("episodes", [])
        for episode_data in episodes:
            episode_data
            if episode_data:
                add_episode(series, episode_data, season_number, tmdb_id)

def add_episode(series, episode_data, season_number, tmdb_id):
    season = get_object_or_404(Season, series=series, season_number=season_number)
    episode_number = episode_data.get("episode_number")

    img_path = episode_data.get("still_path")
    if img_path:
        poster_path = f"media/posters/tv/episode/{tmdb_id}{img_path}"
        if not os.path.exists(poster_path):
            poster_url = f"https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original{img_path}"
            poster_response = requests.get(poster_url)
            if poster_response.status_code == 200:
                os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(poster_path), exist_ok=True)
                with open(poster_path, 'wb') as f:
                    f.write(poster_response.content)

    update_episode = Episode.objects.filter(season=season, episode_number=episode_number).first()
        
    if update_episode:
        update_episode.season = season
        update_episode.title = episode_data.get("name", "")
        update_episode.overview = episode_data.get("overview", "")
        update_episode.runtime = episode_data.get("runtime", "")
        update_episode.episode_number = episode_data.get("episode_number", "")
        update_episode.release_date = episode_data.get("air_date", "")
        update_episode.poster_path = f"posters/tv/episode/{tmdb_id}{img_path}"
        update_episode.save()
    else:
        Episode.objects.create(
            season = season,
            title = episode_data.get("name", ""),
            overview = episode_data.get("overview", ""),
            runtime = episode_data.get("runtime", ""),
            episode_number = episode_data.get("episode_number", ""),
            release_date = episode_data.get("air_date", ""),
            poster_path = f"posters/tv/episode/{tmdb_id}{img_path}"
        )

nginx settings:
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    {{ssl_certificate_key}}
    {{ssl_certificate}}
    server_name movieexpert.xyz;
    return 301 https://www.movieexpert.xyz$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    {{ssl_certificate_key}}
    {{ssl_certificate}}
    server_name www.movieexpert.xyz;
    {{root}}

    {{nginx_access_log}}
    {{nginx_error_log}}

    if ($scheme != "https") {
        rewrite ^ https://$host$uri permanent;
    }

    location ~ /.well-known {
        auth_basic off;
        allow all;
    }

    {{settings}}

    index index.html;

    client_body_buffer_size 64k;
    client_header_buffer_size 64k;
    large_client_header_buffers 4 64k;
    uwsgi_buffer_size 64k;
    uwsgi_buffers 8 64k;
    proxy_buffer_size 64k;
    proxy_buffers 8 64k;

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_read_timeout 3600;
        uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:{{app_port}};
    }

    location ~* ^.+\.(css|js|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|gz|svg|svgz|ttf|otf|woff|woff2|eot|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|webp|zip|swf)$ {
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";
        expires max;
        access_log on;
    }

    if (-f $request_filename) {
        break;
    }
}

i also set uwsgi buffer size to 64k
and also change nginx settings
in local everthing is ok but in production it show me this error

This might be trivial, but can you check if there are any firewalls or port specific rules that dont allow you to make external api calls in Production?

i checked with ping and telnet with my server i cant see nothing wrong

If you do a curl request for the exact same TMDB API call from your production server, do you the right response?
